# ZK: Datebox's calendar doesn't enable the dates back after set constraint as null

Tags: spring, zk

I have 2 dateboxes, which are start date and end date. I set constraint to not allow a user to select end date before the start date, as well as, not allow to select start date after the end date. The constrained dates were disabled properly.

However, the problem is after I click 'clear' button and set the constraint back to null, the disabled date still appeared on the calendar of the dateboxes and I cannot select them.

Here are my code ..

myzul.zul

```
<datebox format="dd/MM/yyyy" id="startDate" value="@bind(vm.startDate)" constraint="@bind(vm.startCons)" onChange="@command('ChangeDate')" />
<datebox format="dd/MM/yyyy" id="endDate" value="@bind(vm.endDate)" constraint="@bind(vm.endCons)" onChange="@command('ChangeDate')" />
.
.
<button label="clear" sclass="fa fa-eraser" onClick="@command('clear')"/>
```

myVM.java

```
public class myVM extends BaseVM {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -213662630713797499L;      
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Date startDate;
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Date endDate;       
    @Setter
    @Getter
    private String startCons = "";
    @Setter
    @Getter
    private String endCons = "";

    @Command
    @NotifyChange({ "*" })
    public void ChangeDateBox() {
        SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    
    if(!Objects.isNull(this.startDate)) {
        this.endCons = "between "+fmt.format(this.startDate)+" and 20201231";
    }
    if(!Objects.isNull(this.endDate)) {
        this.startCons = "between 20200101 and "+fmt.format(this.endDate);
    }

    @Command
    @NotifyChange({ "*" })
    public void clear() {
        this.startDate = null;
        this.endDate = null;
        this.startCons = "";
        this.endCons = "";
    }
```

I also tried to get the constraint date to check and it did set to null.

```
((SimpleDateConstraint)date.getConstraint()).getBeginDate()
```

Please kindly help ..

Answer (score 1):

Congrats, you found an actual bug ;)

When you set a constraint using either between, before or after, then set the constraint to null or empty string, the client doesn't clean the beginning and end fields on the popup calendar before recalculating disabled days.

Posted a bug ticket in the official bug tracker for it [here](https://tracker.zkoss.org/browse/ZK-4641), and here's a workaround:

See the [documentation page for lang-addon.xml](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Client-side_Reference/Language_Definition/javascript) to deploy it globally, or just drop it at the beginning of your zul page for single page deployement.

```
<script><![CDATA[
        zk.afterLoad("zul.db", function () {
            var _xCalendar = {};
            zk.override(zul.db.Calendar.prototype, _xCalendar, {
                _fixConstraint: function() {
                    var result = _xCalendar._fixConstraint.apply(this, arguments);
                    var constraint = this._constraint || '';
                    if (typeof this._constraint != 'string') return;
                    if( constraint == ''){
                        this._beg = null;
                        this._end = null;
                    }
                    return result;
                }
             });
        });
    ]]></script>
```

Comment: Oh..no wonder. I took a whole day to search about this issue. However, thank you @MDuchemin so much for the bug ticket and the helpful workaround :) Have a nice day!

Comment: They there @GaloningLlew! good news, that bug is fixed in the freshly 9.5.1.FL.20201211 and will be available in the full release for 9.5.1.